# Potential PHP memory leak issue with Smarty template?

Tags: php, memory-leaks, smarty

I have a Prestashop server setup, and after install multiple times I am repeatedly getting a PHP error:

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2966923 bytes) in public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 217

On that line it has the following code:

```
            $_output    = ob_get_clean();
```

So I am assuming this is a memory leak, considering it was only trying to allocate ~2.9mb, and reached the memory limit.

I am not sure how to debug this error - PHP is not the language I usually work with, and this is a template/theme I did not create myself. Some assistance debugging this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Put a `phpinfo()` somewhere at the top of script and check the `memory_limit` setting. The message means that "at the running of this function" there is an error. Try to debug if something before takes a lot of memory.